# Method to get a model name through an id, returns nothing but data is there? Laravel-vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to get a model name through the id, I'm doing it through a method on the vue, a route on the web.php and a method in the controller. Like this

Vue, this is one of the if, there are 11 total using if ... else if

```
getSubjectName(m, $id) {
    if (m === "App\\Models\\Category") {
        this.$http.get('/category/' + $id)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('category ' + response.data.name);
                return response.data.name;
    });
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('/category/{id}', 'CategoryController@name');
```

Controller

```
public function name($id) {
    $cat = Category::findOrFail($id);
    return $cat;
}
```

The console.log in the vue returns the correct data but when I use the method it returns nothing.
I'm using it in an Element-ui table like this

```
<el-table>
    <el-table-column>
        <template slot-scope="scope">
            {{getSubjectName(scope.row.subject_type, scope.row.subject_id)}}
        </template>
    </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

I'm at a loss why this is happening and don't know what to do. What can be done to fix this?

Comment: Your function `getSubjectName` does not return anything.

Comment: I think you can do something like `{{getSubjectName(scope.row.subject_type, scope.row.subject_id) | async}}` and then in `getSubjectName` return the `this.$http.get('/category/' + $id)` as a whole

Comment: @Teun the full getSubjectName is not just that part, I'm checking for 11 models in there

Comment: Nothing in your browser console? (You seem to be missing a `}` in your vue code) Is `scope.row.subject_id` set?